# Flask-WTF Instantiate nested Forms

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

i have nested Forms similar to this:

```
class PhoneForm(FlaskForm):
    number = StringField('Phone Number')
    valid_since = None

class AdressForm(FlaskForm):
    phone_number = FormField(PhoneForm)
    city = SelectForm('City')
    name = StringField('Name')
```

I have fiddled around for hours now and i can't find a way to instatiate the forms as i want them. I've tried overriding the constructor and with a static method

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name.data = 'Kevin123'
        self.phone_number = PhoneForm()

    @staticmethod
    def create_form():
        form = AdressForm()
        form.name.data = 'Kevin'
        form.phone_number = PhoneNumber.create_form()  # calls the creator method of the other form
        return form
```

My actual app is a lot larger than this, so i need a way to create Forms by themselves (to set data or choices for select-field) and then add them into the nested form.

From what I've read the only way to pass data into a form in Flask-WTF is by doing:
`form = AdressForm(phone_number='123456')`. Nothing else really works or makes the form "unsubmittable" (i.e the data doesent change after submitting.

Is there a way to do this in Flask-WTF or do i have to try it with regular WTforms.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation, I think you need drop the init stuff. Here is some code for your handler (The Python method that interacts with the form):

```
@app.route('/adress', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    form = forms.AdressForm()
    form.phone_number.number.data = '888.888.8888'
    form.phone_number.valid_since.data = '1984'
```

Does that get you started?

Comment: This does not work in FlaskWTF. If the client sends the forms back with changed values, they dont change in FlaskWTF.

Comment: can you share a little bit of the GET and POST code that's in your handler (as an edit to your original question, please)?

Comment: Thanks i now found it out. It works if i dont set the data when its a POST request, only if its a GET. Now Flask-WTF doesnet get it mixed up anymore.